# manifest issue for shadow plugin with gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-shadow-plugin

I am using gradle v3.4 & shadow plugin v1.2.4.  I am publishing a jar file to my local maven repo using the following inside my build.gradle file

```
mainClassName = 'some.thing.SomeClient'
    jar {
        manifest {
            attributes(
                    'Class-Path': configurations.compile.collect { it.getName() }.join(' '),
                    // 'Main-Class': 'some.thing.SomeClient'
            )
        }
    }

    shadowJar {
        baseName = 'commons-java'
        classifier = null
        version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    }

    artifacts {
        archives shadowJar
    }

    jar.dependsOn shadowJar
```

After publishing, I try to use this dependency inside another project as follows but get the error copied below when I run **gradle build**

```
 /**
 * jar/shadow jar (shadow jar extends jar task to create fat jar)
 */
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Class-Path': configurations.compile.collect { it.getName() }.join(' '),
                //'Main-Class': 'some.thing.SomeClient'
        )
    }
}

shadowJar {
    baseName = 'something-java-client'
    classifier = null
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}

artifacts {
    archives shadowJar
}

jar.dependsOn shadowJar
```

**error**

```
The value of a manifest attribute must not be null (Key=Main-Class).
```

Comment: I have published the jar file with and without a mainclassname (i checked the manifest file in the jar to confirm as well).  I still get the same error regardless of whichever option I chose for the published jar file

Comment: I had the mainClassName attribute in my gradle.settings - removing it from gradle.settings fixed the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was caused by the mainClassName attribute in gradle.properties leading to the exception.  Removing it from gradle.properties fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It also could be that the `mainClassName` is set after the plugin is applied, which seems to be a [known issue](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow/issues/336). The quick and dirty solution is to set the property before applying the plugin, like [this](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow/issues/336#issuecomment-364204059):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:2.0.2'
    }
}

plugins {
    id "application"
}

mainClassName = 'some.thing.SomeClient'

apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'

// ...
```